# Generated artifacts in GitLab cannot be found

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-api

I can find the generated successfully uploaded files in GitLab Artifacts, but I can't get them through the [API](https://repository.prace-ri.eu/git/help/api/job_artifacts.md#download-the-artifacts-archive) or [URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html#from-a-url). It returns 404.

Below is my .gitlab-ci.yml.

```
stages:
  - quality

linting:
  image: python:3.11.4-slim
  stage: quality
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - pip install -U flake8 pylint pylint-exit anybadge
    - pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements-dev.txt
  script:
    - flake8 --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
    - flake8 --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - mkdir pylint
    - pylint --output-format=text **/*.py | tee ./pylint/pylint.log || pylint-exit $?
    - PYLINT_SCORE=$(sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p' ./pylint/pylint.log)
    - anybadge --label=Pylint --file=pylint/pylint.svg --value=$PYLINT_SCORE 2=red 4=orange 8=yellow 10=green
    - echo "Pylint score is $PYLINT_SCORE"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pylint/

analysis:
  image: python:3.11.4-slim
  stage: quality
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - pip install -U bandit
  script:
    - bandit -c pyproject.toml -r **/*.py -f html -o report.html
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expose_as: "Bandit"
    paths:
      - report.html

unit-test:
  image: python:3.11.4-slim
  stage: quality
  before_script:
    - pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements-dev.txt
  script:
    - coverage run -m pytest
    - coverage report -m
    - coverage xml
    - coverage html
  coverage: '/(?i)total.*? (100(?:\.0+)?\%|[1-9]?\d(?:\.\d+)?\%)$/'
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - htmlcov/
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage.xml
  allow_failure: false
```

Only unit-test artifacts are available. The other two can only get files through this [API](https://repository.prace-ri.eu/git/help/api/job_artifacts.md#get-job-artifacts).